# Gulp run-sequence "'taskname' is a not valid task string" error

Tags: gulp, run-sequence

I faced a stange problem. Tasks sequence is right, syntax too, but it's not working and trowns an error:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
gulp.task("Markup-Build", function(callback) {
    return runSequence("Markup-Clean", [
        ["Markup-Build-Styles", "Markup-Collect-Styles"],
        ["Markup-Build-Views", "Markup-Collect-Views"]
    ], callback);
});
```

[image: Console Output]

I need some help. What I doing wrong?

(Dependent tasks are working, I checked names too, no misprints)

Comment: `run-sequence` doesn't accept nested arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant have nested array change it to

```
  return runSequence("Markup-Clean",
    ["Markup-Build-Styles", "Markup-Collect-Styles"],
    ["Markup-Build-Views", "Markup-Collect-Views"]
, callback);
```